# Eager Loading Condition is count() in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eager-loading

I'm trying to get some data from Table A which has results in Table B using eager loading and exclude data with no results in Table B in Laravel. But I can't seem get what I want.

Here are the tables I'm using:

```
 * table_a                    * table_b
+---------+                  +------------+
+ id      +                  + id         +
+ user_id +                  + table_a_id +
+ colA    +                  + colA       +
+ colB    +                  + colB       +
+---------+                  +------------+
```

What result I want is this:

```
data: [
    {
       id:       1,
       user_id:  1,
       colA:     "Some text here",
       colB:     "Other text here",
       table_b:  [
           {
               id:          2,
               table_a_id:  1,
               colA:        "some text here",
               colB:        "other text here"
           }
       ]
    },
    {
       id:       2,
       user_id:  1,
       colA:     "Some text here",
       colB:     "Other text here",
       table_b:  [
           {
               id:          5,
               table_a_id:  1,
               colA:        "some text here",
               colB:        "other text here"
           },
           {
               id:          6,
               table_a_id:  1,
               colA:        "some text here",
               colB:        "other text here"
           }
       ]
    }
]
```

But I get something like this:

```
data: [
    {
       id:       1,
       user_id:  1,
       colA:     "Some text here",
       colB:     "Other text here",
       table_b:  [
           {
               id:          2,
               table_a_id:  1,
               colA:        "some text here",
               colB:        "other text here"
           }
       ]
    },
    {
       id:       2,
       user_id:  1,
       colA:     "Some text here",
       colB:     "Other text here",
       table_b:  [
           {
               id:          5,
               table_a_id:  1,
               colA:        "some text here",
               colB:        "other text here"
           },
           {
               id:          6,
               table_a_id:  1,
               colA:        "some text here",
               colB:        "other text here"
           }
       ]
    },
    {
       id:       3,
       user_id:  1,
       colA:     "Some text here",
       colB:     "Other text here",
       table_b:  null
    },
    {
       id:       4,
       user_id:  1,
       colA:     "Some text here",
       colB:     "Other text here",
       table_b:  null
    }
]
```

I tried this:

```
$user->table_a->withTableB()->where('table_b', '<>', 'null')->get(); //this doesn't work obviously
```

And I have no idea how to do it. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any models set up? If so, you can pretty easily solve this using Eloquent and relationships, check the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships

Comment: yes, but i dont have any idea how to exclude a data with out results from other table.